# Heroku error with React and Express: cannot find app.js

Tags: reactjs, express, heroku, create-react-app

I have built few apps and decided to host one on the Heroku. I have configured Express server to run files in Build folder:
server/server.js:

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const publicPath = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'build');
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.use(express.static(publicPath));
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(publicPath, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server is up!');
});
```

When I try to run the server locally everything works fine. I have hosted the whole project on GitHub (via file upload as the port I would need is blocked) and set Heroku to fetch the project from there. I have set the Procfile to this:

```
web: node server/server.js
```

I expected Heroku to run the server and the server to get the files from the build folder of the project. However Heroku CLI shows following error:

```
2019-11-01T20:14:22.015987+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js`
2019-11-01T20:14:23.648922+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2019-11-01T20:14:23.687276+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2019-11-01T20:14:23.691982+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607228+00:00 app[web.1]: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607245+00:00 app[web.1]: throw err;
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607246+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607247+00:00 app[web.1]:
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607248+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Cannot find module '/app/app.js'
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607253+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607254+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607255+00:00 app[web.1]: at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
2019-11-01T20:14:23.607259+00:00 app[web.1]: at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
2019-11-01T20:14:23.60726+00:00 app[web.1]: at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

package.json:

```
 "name": "ai",
  "version": "0.9.0",
  "private": true,
  "engines": {
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "node": "^v10.15.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "emailjs-com": "^2.4.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "i18next": "^17.0.11",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^3.0.3",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.11",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-i18next": "^10.12.2",
    "react-image-gallery": "^0.9.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server/server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Build goes alright but then the app.js cannot be found. The path in error log doesn't give me much sense - shouldn't it look for a different (minified) file in build folder? There is no app/ folder in my project on top of that. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your project is looking for an app.js file by default. If server.js is your main project file,  you might need to find where app/app.js is specified and change it to server/server.js